# How to implement a JavaScript function call as a condition in xsl 1.0?

Tags: xslt-1.0

How to implement a JavaScript function call as a condition in  in xsl 1.0?

I need to call function in the test condition of xsl:if and compare it to a value. How to do this?

```
    <xsl if test = "func() = 'true'">
        <xsl:eval>findnodevalue(this.parentNode,"IsUserAuthorized")</xsl:eval>
    </xsl:if>
```

Please note that the            findnodevalue(this.parentNode,"IsUserAuthorized")                 works perfectly fine and returns the desired result if used separately.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: XSLT (whatever version is in ASP classic) supports JavaScript UDFs (User Defined Functions)?

Comment: Yes, the function in itself is working pretty well but only when I use it within xsl:eval tags. But when I try doing the same thing within a xsl:if test = "func() = 'true'"  its not working

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Does the function get executed at all? And, *if so*, then isn't it a matter of just invoking it as `func(.., 'IsUserAuthorized') == true` or similar?

Comment: The function doesn't  get invoked at all. So it doesn't do anything and doesn't get into the 'if' block

Comment: The *real* XSL is `<xsl:if ..`, right? Please make sure to pose *accurate* code/markup. How do you know that `func` is not being executed?